# Spring Boot OAuth2 Custom Login Form Use case

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

The oauth2 JWT project from the "Getting Started Spring Security and Angular JS Series" has a custom login. Adding the same code for a custom login page to the oauth2-vanilla project fails as the authorization code is always empty in the login response. I also tried porting the Sparklr2 (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/tree/master/samples/oauth2) code into Spring Boot, but the authorization code is still empty. If this is not a bug, are there any examples for this use case?
My problem was reported at this GitHub url:
Login form URL: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/resources/templates/login.ftl
Authorize form URL: https://github.com/dsyer/spring-security-angular/blob/master/oauth2/authserver/src/main/resources/templates/authorize.ftl

**HTTP TRACE FOLLOWS**

## ROOT CONTEXT

302 GET http://localhost:8080/user
  Request headers:
    Host: localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    X-XSRF-TOKEN: e73f9d6b-9d82-4f09-a327-520c45add5a0
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=0A8D06F75D8DAEFE88441D80BA8C0C53; XSRF-TOKEN=e73f9d6b-9d82-4f09-a327-520c45add5a0
    Connection: keep-alive
  Response headers:
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:59:58 GMT
    Expires: 0
    Location: http://localhost:8080/login
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    x-content-type-options: nosniff

200 GET http://localhost:8080/home.html
  Request headers:
    Host: localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest 
    X-XSRF-TOKEN: e73f9d6b-9d82-4f09-a327-520c45add5a0
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=0A8D06F75D8DAEFE88441D80BA8C0C53; XSRF-TOKEN=e73f9d6b-9d82-4f09-a327-520c45add5a0
    Connection: keep-alive
  Response headers:
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Content-Length: 219
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
    Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:59:58 GMT
    Expires: 0
    Last-Modified: Wed, 25 Mar 2015 01:50:42 GMT
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    X-Application-Context: bootstrap
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    x-content-type-options: nosniff

302 GET http://localhost:8080/resource/
  Request headers:
    Host: localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    X-XSRF-TOKEN: e73f9d6b-9d82-4f09-a327-520c45add5a0
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=0A8D06F75D8DAEFE88441D80BA8C0C53; XSRF-TOKEN=e73f9d6b-9d82-4f09-a327-520c45add5a0
    Connection: keep-alive
  Response headers:
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:59:58 GMT
    Expires: 0
    Location: http://localhost:8080/login
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    x-content-type-options: nosniff

302 GET http://localhost:8080/login
  Request headers:
    Host: localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    X-XSRF-TOKEN: e73f9d6b-9d82-4f09-a327-520c45add5a0
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=0A8D06F75D8DAEFE88441D80BA8C0C53; XSRF-TOKEN=e73f9d6b-9d82-4f09-a327-520c45add5a0
    Connection: keep-alive
  Response headers:
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:59:58 GMT
    Expires: 0
    Location: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&response_type=code&state=ZORNNY
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    x-content-type-options: nosniff

302 GET http://localhost:8080/login
  Request headers:
    Host: localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    X-XSRF-TOKEN: e73f9d6b-9d82-4f09-a327-520c45add5a0
    X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=0A8D06F75D8DAEFE88441D80BA8C0C53; XSRF-TOKEN=e73f9d6b-9d82-4f09-a327-520c45add5a0
    Connection: keep-alive
  Response headers:
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:59:58 GMT
    Expires: 0
    Location: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&response_type=code&state=knNsMF
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    x-content-type-options: nosniff

## LOGIN

302 GET http://localhost:8080/login

Request headers:
    Host: localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=681144B950A553779BA1722D4166DB78; XSRF-TOKEN=c46af943-e520-411b-b96d-e3e45f3196fb
    Connection: keep-alive

Response headers:
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:06:32 GMT
    Expires: 0
    Location: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&response_type=code&state=lpTB5d
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    x-content-type-options: nosniff

302 GET http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&response_type=code&state=lpTB5d

Request headers:
    Host: localhost:9999
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=681144B950A553779BA1722D4166DB78; XSRF-TOKEN=c46af943-e520-411b-b96d-e3e45f3196fb
    Connection: keep-alive

Response headers:
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:06:32 GMT
    Expires: 0
    Location: http://localhost:9999/uaa/login
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=FD174AF5EF78ECF13F0284101578C6F8; Path=/uaa/; HttpOnly
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    x-content-type-options: nosniff

200 GET http://localhost:9999/uaa/login

Request headers:
    Host: localhost:9999
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://localhost:8080/
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=FD174AF5EF78ECF13F0284101578C6F8; JSESSIONID=681144B950A553779BA1722D4166DB78; XSRF-TOKEN=c46af943-e520-411b-b96d-e3e45f3196fb
    Connection: keep-alive

Response headers:
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Content-Language: en-US
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
    Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:06:32 GMT
    Expires: 0
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked
    X-Application-Context: application:9999
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    x-content-type-options: nosniff

200 GET wro.css

200 GET wro.js

## LOGIN SUBMIT

302 POST http://localhost:9999/uaa/login

Request headers:
    Host: localhost:9999
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://localhost:9999/uaa/login
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=FD174AF5EF78ECF13F0284101578C6F8; JSESSIONID=681144B950A553779BA1722D4166DB78; XSRF-TOKEN=c46af943-e520-411b-b96d-e3e45f3196fb
    Connection: keep-alive

Response headers:
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:24:02 GMT
    Expires: 0
    Location: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&response_type=code&state=lpTB5d
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=12D1C160B5CDDEAD0F9C96E9FB9E53A9; Path=/uaa/; HttpOnly
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    x-content-type-options: nosniff

Form Data Parameter:
    username:"######"
    password:"######"
    _csrf:"ba0f23da-8059-4b7b-89df-d9998d8de4fb"

200 GET http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&response_type=code&state=lpTB5d

Request headers:
     Host: localhost:9999
     User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
     Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
     Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
     Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
     Referer: http://localhost:9999/uaa/login
     Cookie: JSESSIONID=12D1C160B5CDDEAD0F9C96E9FB9E53A9; JSESSIONID=681144B950A553779BA1722D4166DB78; XSRF-TOKEN=c46af943-e520-411b-b96d-e3e45f3196fb
     Connection: keep-alive

Response headers:
     Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
     Content-Language: en-US
     Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
     Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:24:02 GMT
     Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
     Pragma: no-cache
     Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
     Transfer-Encoding: chunked
     X-Application-Context: application:9999
     X-Frame-Options: DENY
     X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
     x-content-type-options: nosniff

304 GET wro.css

304 GET wro.js

## APPROVE

302 POST http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize

Request headers:
    Host: localhost:9999
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&response_type=code&state=lpTB5d
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=12D1C160B5CDDEAD0F9C96E9FB9E53A9; JSESSIONID=681144B950A553779BA1722D4166DB78; XSRF-TOKEN=c46af943-e520-411b-b96d-e3e45f3196fb
    Connection: keep-alive

Response headers:
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store
    Content-Language: en-US
    Content-Length: 0
    Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:31:51 GMT
    Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
    Location: http://localhost:8080/login?error=access_denied&error_description=User%20denied%20access&state=lpTB5d
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    X-Application-Context: application:9999
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    x-content-type-options: nosniff

Form Data Parameter:
    user_oauth_approval:"true"
    _csrf:"32e46c90-0aac-4120-8d31-f31a7e6fe0ec"

401 GET http://localhost:8080/login?error=access_denied&error_description=User%20denied%20access&state=lpTB5d

Request headers:
    Host: localhost:8080
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
    Referer: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&response_type=code&state=lpTB5d
    Cookie: JSESSIONID=681144B950A553779BA1722D4166DB78; XSRF-TOKEN=c46af943-e520-411b-b96d-e3e45f3196fb
    Connection: keep-alive

Response headers:
    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
    Content-Language: en-US
    Content-Length: 341
    Content-Type: text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
    Date: Tue, 19 May 2015 15:31:52 GMT
    Expires: 0
    Pragma: no-cache
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
    X-Frame-Options: DENY
    X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
    x-content-type-options: nosniff

### LOGIN LOGS

2015-06-09 02:32:02.787 DEBUG 5312 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
'/login'; against '/login' 
2015-06-09 02:32:02.788 DEBUG 5312 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Request is to process authentication
2015-06-09 02:32:02.788 DEBUG 5312 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     : Authentication attempt using org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider
2015-06-09 02:32:02.814  INFO 5312 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Tue Jun 09 
02:32:02 EDT 2015, principal=phil, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffed504: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 4E22482896B7A9D7E427101CBC1187D2}] 
2015-06-09 02:32:02.814 DEBUG 5312 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.authentication.session.ChangeSessionIdAuthenticationStrategy@684222cb
2015-06-09 02:32:02.815  INFO 5312 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Tue Jun 09
 02:32:02 EDT 2015, principal=phil, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffed504: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 4E22482896B7A9D7E427101CBC1187D2}]
2015-06-09 02:32:02.815 DEBUG 5312 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] s.CompositeSessionAuthenticationStrategy : Delegating to org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfAuthenticationStrategy@51738bda
2015-06-09 02:32:02.816 DEBUG 5312 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : Authentication success. Updating SecurityContextHolder to contain: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bbd7aa2f: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@347d1b: Username: phil; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffed504: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 4E22482896B7A9D7E427101CBC1187D2; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER
2015-06-09 02:32:02.817  INFO 5312 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] o.s.b.a.audit.listener.AuditListener     : AuditEvent [timestamp=Tue Jun 09 02:32:02 EDT 2015, principal=phil, type=AUTHENTICATION_SUCCESS, data={details=org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffed504: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 4E22482896B7A9D7E427101CBC1187D2}]
2015-06-09 02:32:02.817 DEBUG 5312 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] RequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler : Redirecting to DefaultSavedRequest Url: http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&response_type=code&state=4WtAHc
2015-06-09 02:32:02.818 DEBUG 5312 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] o.s.s.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy        : Redirecting to 'http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize?client_id=acme&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Flogin&response_type=code&state=4WtAHc'
2015-06-09 02:32:02.818 DEBUG 5312 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext stored to HttpSession: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@bbd7aa2f: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bbd7aa2f: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@347d1b: Username: phil; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffed504: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 4E22482896B7A9D7E427101CBC1187D2; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'

### APPROVE LOGS

2015-06-09 03:01:44.194 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
2015-06-09 03:01:44.194 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : Obtained a valid SecurityContext from SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT: 'org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextImpl@bbd50027: Authentication: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bbd50027: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@347d1b: Username: phil; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffc7f0c: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 96B6C1DF8C52F23738AB7732C2A7AD70; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'
2015-06-09 03:01:44.194 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
2015-06-09 03:01:44.195 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@627aa865
2015-06-09 03:01:44.195 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'
2015-06-09 03:01:44.195 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
2015-06-09 03:01:44.195 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
'/oauth/authorize'; against '/logout'
2015-06-09 03:01:44.195 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
2015-06-09 03:01:44.195 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
'/oauth/authorize'; against '/login'
2015-06-09 03:01:44.195 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter' 
2015-06-09 03:01:44.196 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter' 
2015-06-09 03:01:44.196 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter' 
2015-06-09 03:01:44.196 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  : SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bbd50027: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@347d1b: Username: phil; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffc7f0c: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 96B6C1DF8C52F23738AB7732C2A7AD70; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER' 
2015-06-09 03:01:44.196 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter' 
2015-06-09 03:01:44.196 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
2015-06-09 03:01:44.196 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
2015-06-09 03:01:44.196 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
'/oauth/authorize'; against '/admin/**' 

2015-06-09 03:01:44.196 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /oauth/authorize; Attributes: [authenticated] 

2015-06-09 03:01:44.196 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@bbd50027: Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@347d1b: Username: phil; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true; AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true; AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@fffc7f0c: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 96B6C1DF8C52F23738AB7732C2A7AD70; Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER 

2015-06-09 03:01:44.197 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.access.vote.AffirmativeBased       : Voter: org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@2b6b3792, returned: 1 

2015-06-09 03:01:44.197 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful 

2015-06-09 03:01:44.197 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change
Authentication object 

2015-06-09 03:01:44.197 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain 

2015-06-09 03:01:44.198 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /oauth/authorize 

2015-06-09 03:01:44.199 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] .s.o.p.e.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.View org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(java.util.Map,java.util.Map,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)]

2015-06-09 03:01:44.219 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter     : Chain processed normally 

2015-06-09 03:01:44.219 DEBUG 9104 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed 

2015-06-09 03:01:44.252 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
'/oauth/authorize'; against '/css/**' 
2015-06-09 03:01:44.252 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
'/oauth/authorize'; against '/js/**' 

2015-06-09 03:01:44.252 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
'/oauth/authorize'; against '/images/**'  
2015-06-09 03:01:44.252 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
'/oauth/authorize'; against '/**/favicon.ico'   
2015-06-09 03:01:44.252 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
'/oauth/authorize'; against '/error'  
2015-06-09 03:01:44.253 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/metrics']  
2015-06-09 03:01:44.253 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
'/oauth/authorize'; against '/metrics'  
2015-06-09 03:01:44.253 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/login']  
2015-06-09 03:01:44.253 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
'/oauth/authorize'; against '/login' 
2015-06-09 03:01:44.253 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : Trying to match using Ant [pattern='/oauth/authorize']   
2015-06-09 03:01:44.253 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.u.matcher.AntPathRequestMatcher  : Checking match of request :
'/oauth/authorize'; against '/oauth/authorize'   
2015-06-09 03:01:44.253 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.web.util.matcher.OrRequestMatcher  : matched  
2015-06-09 03:01:44.253 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 1 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter'  
2015-06-09 03:01:44.253 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 2 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter' 
2015-06-09 03:01:44.253 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No HttpSession currently exists  
2015-06-09 03:01:44.253 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: null. A new one will be created.  
2015-06-09 03:01:44.254 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'  
2015-06-09 03:01:44.254 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@627aa865  
2015-06-09 03:01:44.254 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /oauth/authorize at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'CsrfFilter'  
2015-06-09 03:01:44.254 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost:9999/uaa/oauth/authorize   
2015-06-09 03:01:44.255 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] w.c.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository : SecurityContext is empty or
contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.   
2015-06-09 03:01:44.255 DEBUG 9104 --- [io-9999-exec-10] s.s.w.c.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter : SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed

Comment: In github, you have mentioned that the `AccessConfirmationController` is not getting the token. But here you have mentioned that the login response does not contain authorization code. Can you rephrase your question and explain the exact situation.

Comment: In /login shouldn't the form data parameter name be `username` instead of `user_name`.

Comment: There was also a Invalid CSRF token in the logs after I approved the client.

Comment: Can you post the code for the custom login page?

Comment: I added links to forms and corrected the typo I made for user_name form parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   <input type="hidden" name="scope.openid" value="true"/>
   <input type="hidden" name="scope.openid" value="false"/>
```

The client scope is not set in the authorize form. Add extra inputs to the form for approve and deny requests as shown above.